# Will Peer to Peer replication still work with RPC out disabled?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, configuration, transactional-replication

PCI Compliance is failing due to "Microsoft SQL Server Database Link Crawling Command Execution"

There is no solution available however they recommend a Workaround:

> Disable RPC_Out and xp_cmdshell for this issue.

We currently use Peer to Peer transactional replication, and the RPC Out is a server option on linked servers...

Would peer-to-peer replication still work if that is disabled as per the 'workaround' ?

Comment: As far as I know, disabling RPC would break a whole lot of things for replication.